# CSS padding-top trick won't give me correct proportions

Tags: html, css

It is said that *"padding in percentages is based on parent element's width"*. `Padding-top: 100%` with `width: 100%` should give me square shape. Which isn't exactly my case and I don't understand why.

Let's say I have a structure like this:

```
<body>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="page">
      <div class="group">
        <div class="section">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

I want to make "section" square. I also want to make some border on a page. So I do this:

```
 .wrapper {
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;
    justify-content: center;
  }
  .page {
    /* Making border this way */
    width: 95%;
  }
  .group {
    width: 100%;
  }
  .section {
    /* Making square */
    width: 100%;
    padding-top: 100%;
  }
```

But it turns out that my "square" is a bit taller than it should. Like 5% taller.
In my understanding I'm telling browser "take 100%w of 'group' which equals to 100%w of 'section' btw and make 'section' this high". Obviously it's not working as I expected.

So any help explaining what's wrong with my logic or, better yet, how to keep relative proportions of elements on all screens without going absolute numbers would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

Well it doesn't really mean "Add this much height".

Padding in CSS is the element property you set, to add space between the border of your element and everything it contains.

So, if you want space between your element and another element, you use "margin" and if you want to create space inside of an element you use padding. (or margin on the child-elements)

Answer (score 1):

```
.section {
  /* Making square */
  width: 100%;
  padding-top: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

[Box-sizing Border Box](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing)

By default in the CSS box model, the width and height you assign to an element is applied only to the element's content box. If the element has any border or padding, this is then added to the width and height to arrive at the size of the box that's rendered on the screen.

Answer (score 0):

I found out the answer. I thought "padding-top" was something like "make me shape this tall" but it actually means "add this much height to this shape".

The shape was containing some text label so padding was added on top of the height of said label.